# how can I send props to other file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I send props to another file?

I have a component file. And there is an array where data are pushed. If the user click ok, then I want the array to another file.

example:
sizeComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const AboveSize = ({ data, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
    <Text style={{color: '#333', fontSize: 16}}>Bekleidungsgröße</Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key}
          horizontal
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
            return {
              index,
              length: 200,
              offset: height * index
            }
          }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ccc', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 8, height: 77, width: 77, margin: 12, marginLeft: 0, backgroundColor: data.includes(item.size) ? 'red' : 'blue'}}>
                <Text style={{color: data.includes(item.size) ? '#fff' : '#333', fontSize: 20}}>{item.size}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          }}
       />
    </View>
  </View>
  )
};

export default pure(AboveSize);
```

Main.js

```
import SizeComponent from 'sizeComponent';
/* Size from Mock Data */
const productData = [
  {
    item: {
      id: 1,
      name:"Calvin Klein Bag",
      price:"29.99€",
      size: [
        {
          key: "1",
          size: "XS"
        },
        {
          key: "2",
          size: "S",
        },
        {
          key: "3",
          size: "M"
        },
        {
          key: "4",
          size: "L"
        },
        {
          key: "5",
          size: "XL"
        },
        {
          key: "6",
          size: "XXL"
        },
        {
          key: "7",
          size: "XXXL"
        }
      ],
    }
  }];
const [productSize, setProductSize] = useState([]);

...
<SizeComponent data={productData} onPress={() => console.log('I want here the data from the component file which was selected')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sizeComponent.js change the onPress method to the following code:
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>onPress(item)}`
so when the onPress is called the selected item will be passed to the callback method which you can access like this

```
<SizeComponent data={productData} onPress={(item) => {//the seleteced item will be accessible here })
```

Answer (score 1):

React Native applications are built using components that manage state internally.

To globalize your state there is a state management libraries like **Redux** exist to solve this issue. Redux provides a central location for all the states of an application where each component can access the values stored in the state.

reducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
const INITIAL_STATE = { table:[] };
const reducers = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PUSH_TABLE":
      state.table.push(action.value)
      return { ...state, table: state.table };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default combineReducers({ reducers: reducers });
```

action.js

```js
export const pushTable = (title) => ({
  type: "PUSH_TABLE",
  value: title
});
```

app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ListScreen from "./src/ListScreen";
import ModalScreen from "./src/ModalScreen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./src/reducer";
const store = createStore(reducer);
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainStackNavigator />
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Table.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { pushTable } from "./action";
class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
          <Button
            title={"PUSH TABLE"}
            onPress={() => this.props.pushTable("NICE") }
          />
          {this.props.reducers.table.map((cel, index) => (
            <Text>{cel} {index}</Text>
          ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
const mdtp = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators( { pushTable, }, dispatch );
const mtp = (state) => {
  const { reducers } = state;
  return { reducers };
};
export default connect(mtp, mdtp)(Table);
```